# default value for PropertiesPlaceholderConfigurer in spring?

Tags: spring, config

if I reference a variable in my bean definition, and provide it from PropertiesPlaceholderConfigurer,
but don't provide it in any properties files,
Spring fails saying it can't resolve the var.

is there any way to provide a default?

Answer (score 2):

Since Spring 3.0 you can provide a default in your placeholder.

For example, if you had a String property, this placeholder would have a default value of "default": `${propertyName:default}`

Comment: Could this be more beautiful!  Exactly what I was looking for!  I'm using this to have defaults against missing system properties in my XML config files.